# React with MVC, simple app, getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am creating a test React web application using documentation [here](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) in VS 2015 but I am getting error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

my code

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="commentBox">
      Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
  </div>
);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<CommentBox />,
document.getElementById('content')
);
```

[image]

[image]

the nuget package I have installed

[image]

Comment: React template are not support anymore. I get the same issue like this. You need to update to VS 2017 in order to use React in VS

Comment: This error is occurring in browser, how is this link to VS?

Comment: You using MVC 4 with react and to me that package is not need . The detail of package can be found [at](https://reactjs.net/). In VS 2017 there is built in React & .Net template you can check that out. And main reason is you dont use babel to compile your code from ES6 to ES5

Answer (score 2):

in an image, a list of packages is for server-side rendering. you are trying to render as client side.

**React.Web.MVC4** NuGet package is for server side. 
for example:

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                Hello, {this.props.name}! I am a CommentBox.
            </div>
        );
    }
} /* Script/App.js */
```

```
@using React.Web.mvc

@Html.React("CommentBox",new{
    name="John"
})  /* Index.cshtml */
```

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration = new ReactSiteConfiguration()
                .AddScript("~/script/App.js");
        }
    }
}  /* AppStart/reactConfig.cs */
```

[react.js with mvc server side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myoghjBrTbU&t=38s)